# Number Search Coderbyte Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am solving this problem at coderbyte

**Using the Ruby language, have the function NumberSearch(str) take the str parameter, search for all the numbers in the string, add them together, then return that final number. For example: if str is "88Hello 3World!" the output should be 91. You will have to differentiate between single digit numbers and multiple digit numbers like in the example above. So "55Hello" and "5Hello 5" should return two different answers. Each string will contain at least one letter or symbol.**

My first attempt to solve the number search problem results in the code below. However, after submitting it, it did not work for the case of `"1 2 3 4 k10"` which is obvious after comparing my code.

The solution would have been more elegant had I used regular expression and splitted it based on non-digit character, and then added each element in the splitted array, but I wanted to try solving using the long way.

How would this code be fixed so that it also works for the case of `"1 2 3 4 k10"`? the intent of my code is to search all the elements in the string and if it sees more digit in a block of string, it would add up the string. If the next string is not a digit then it resets the `num_str`. I would get an array of number string which is `num_arr`.

My original codes:

```
def NumberSearch(str)
  num_str = ""    #store numbers with more than one digit
  num_arr = []    #number storage
  sum = 0
  i = 0
  while i<=str.length
    if str[i,1].to_i>0
      num_str = num_str + str[i,1]
    elsif str[i,1].to_i == 0    #str[i].to_i is 0
      num_arr << num_str.to_i
      num_str = ""    #reset string number
    end

    i += 1
  end

  num_arr.each do |x|
    sum = sum + x
  end
  return sum

end
```

Editted:

Following Beartech's suggestion below, I updated the code. I use string `.include?` method instead of the array `.include?` method. Also the method name came from Coderbyte. Using capital letter in method name is un-rubyist.

```
def NumberSearch(str) 
  num_str = ""    #store numbers with more than one digit
  num_arr = []    #number storage
  sum = 0
  i = 0
  #str<<"required!"  #add nondigit character for code to work
  while i<str.length
    if "0123456789".include? str[i,1]
      num_str = num_str + str[i,1]
    elsif   #note the "required" was added earlier because of this section here
      num_arr << num_str.to_i   
      num_str = ""    #reset string number
    end

    i += 1
  end
  num_arr.each do |x|
    sum = sum + x
  end
  return sum

end
```

Comment: I assume you aware that `"a".to_i => 0`. How do you distinguish between a letter and zero?

Comment: I know that you're not interested in a short solution, but I have to post it nonetheless: `str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).inject(:+)`

Comment: Guy, you need to understand that @Stefan cannot help himself.

Comment: well, a short solution cannot help me understand Ruby considering I am new to the language.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes I am aware that `"a".to_i => 0`. I was using `str.is_a? String` and `str.is_a? Numeric` before but realize that they are already in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def number_search(check_str) 

       # do not use capital letter at beginning of  name, use "snake case" if you want to do it the ruby way
       # initialize empty arrays to hold the number and the group of numbers

  num_hold = []
  num_arr = []

       # split your string into individual characters

  y = check_str.split('')

       # add an element to the signal the end of the array, use any non-number.

  y << "hey!"

       #now iterate through your array using `each`.

  y.each do |char|  

       # if the char passed in is a digit then put it in the holder array and go to the next character.

    if %w(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).include? char
      num_hold << char

       # if it's not a digit, then take all of the digits currently in the holder and join them.
       # then take the joined string, make it an integer and put it in the array of numbers.

    else
      num_arr << num_hold.join.to_i
      num_hold = []   # be sure and reset the num_hold array to empty
    end
  end

       # now we use another iterator, `inject` to add up all of the numbers in the array.
  num_arr.inject {|sum, n| sum + n}
end
```

I've added a lot of comments to help you see what's going on since you say you are new. Two things to note:

1) The addition of "hey!" was needed because the logic in our `.each` statement would not know what to do with the last number if it wasn't followed by a non-digit, so it would get lost.

2) The use of iterators like `.each` and `.inject`. If you are going to learn Ruby then the best thing you can do for yourself is go to the docs and read all of the methods available in the module Enumerable. Seriously, go now and read it http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html

This will save you so many while/if/else/until/for statements. There is huge power in the Enumerables. Many of these are inherited by Array and Hash.

`inject` is one some people have a tough time with, I know it didn't seem obvious to me at first. But it basically is iterating through the list passing each item into the loop, but unlike each it has `memo` (here I use the variable `sum`) which is just the starting value. You could make the starting value anything. So if you wanted to add 10 to the total of the array you would set `memo = 10` to start with. Note that I did not set `sum` to anything. If you don't set it, it gets the first value in the array and starts |n| off on the second value.

I would go through this solution, and also see if you can refactor it into:

```
str.scan(/\d+/).inject(0) {|sum,n| sum + n.to_i}
```

This is the heart of a language like Ruby. It lets you chain your methods to make complicated structures into one-liners like above.

Comment: The most important thing I learned in programming is, when I have to write a piece of custom code, I ask "is there already a method, module, class or gem that does this?" and search google for it.

Comment: nice! This is a great solution with full of explanation which helps me understand the problem better. I updated my code to include string of number `0123456789.include? str[i,1]`. I was wondering why I also needed to add a non-digit string to the function parameter, `str` then I realized it is because of the `else` logic.

Comment: Exactly, there are certainly other ways to do it, but it's just so simple to tack on a non-digit to get the code to work. I started to figure out some other way before I realized that.